# How to program an offbrand arduino uno?

Tags: sketch

So I recently bought this off brand arduino uno from betemcu.cn.
it says its r3 compatible.

Can I program this thing with the arduino coder or do I need to use something else? whenever I try uploading the code it says "problem uploading to board"

what settings or program should I use to code this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Ask betemcu.cn for docs?

Comment: You installed the serial driver, right?

Comment: Try uploading program using ICSP.!

Comment: Have you tried changing the type of board in the Arduino interface ? For your board I would try the Arduino Uno setting. Also check that the correct serial port is selected (yes I know you connect via USB, it's a virtual COM port I'm talking about).

Answer (score 3):

**The issue is probably that you need a driver for the onboard CH340G USB-to-serial bridge.**

The Baite Electronics Arduino clones are generally of good quality and work well.
There are some differences between them and Arduino-brand Arduinos. Two notable ones are a different voltage regulator and (probably the issue here) a different USB-to-serial bridge IC.  The Arduino brand products use an FTDI IC and Baite uses, in this case, the CH340 USB bridge IC.

The product is described [**on this webpage**](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/10pcs-lot-high-quality-UNO-R3-MEGA328P-CH340G-for-Arduino-Compatible-Improved-version-expert-version-NO/812021_1933705621.html) and you will see that they say

> UNO MEGA328P **CH340G** for Arduino Compatible

The CH340G relates to the USB interface IC.
Until about a year ago the USB driver in windows worked with most common USB ICs as well as with FTDI ICs.  However, FTDI changed their system so that the Windows driver will now only work with FTDI brand ICs. So it is now necessary to load a driver into the PC (whether Windows, Linux or other O/S) to suit the CH340.

If you email them Baite will provide a link to the CH340 driver, but they do not usually provide it on their website (reason unknown to me.)

Or, you can obtain a driver from numerous websites.
[**A web search on eg:  driver ch340 baite arduino**](https://www.google.co.nz/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ch340%20baite%20arduino%20driver)
turns up many pages.   How good or how safe any of these is is TBD.

[**This page**](http://www.arduined.eu/ch340g-converter-windows-7-driver-download/) claims to provide a Windows 7 CH340G driver and install instructions

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ix4t-_RZ7NI) describes how to install a driver and provides a link to [this page](http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html) which lists a number of drivers.

[**This page discusses the issue**](http://doityourselfchristmas.com/forums/showthread.php?14690-CH340-USB-RS232-Driver)

Comment: betemcu.cn/Baite (is there a difference?) should pay you for offering support on their products!

Comment: @RespawnedFluff I know you've heard me say it before but, for others: I have no relationship with Baite except as a satisfied customer. I've bought a few orders from them - maybe $200 overall more or less. I've been happy with the product, the price and the responsiveness. Their documentation is essentially nonexistent - which seems strange considering how easy it would be to provide basic data. Even the driver non provision is strange - they will provide (afair) a temporary link if you ask (which I did at one stage). I have heard various tales about Arduino clones which work poorly  ....

Comment: .... or not at all or are of generally low quality or poorly made. Anything I've bought from them (that has actually got used :-) ) has worked as expected. Others' experiences with them may be different and I have no involvement whatsoever in their dealings with anyone except me.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Re Baite/Bete - the photos that Corey supplied seem to be an essentially exact match for the ones on their website and the PCB silkscreen contains both Baite as a company name and betemcu.cn as a website. So one and the same it seems.

Comment: Re: "I know you've heard me say it before". Actually, I haven't. And I didn't mean to sound like you were dishonest, hiding something, or anything remotely dubious like that. I'm sorry if I came across that way, and I probably did given the length of your reply. Cheers.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff No - no problem - I just talk too much :-). You raised a valid point which I thought was worth addressing for others. I usually add some sort of disclaimer in such posts but didn't do soon that occasion - my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Just install your driver. Some might install automatically. Then try to upload the sketch using arduino IDE.